You may have two independent copies of golang.org/x/net/trace in your binary
I have a Go program with the following go.mod:
go 1.21.12

require (
    github.com/containerd/containerd v1.7.16
    github.com/emicklei/go-restful/v3 v3.12.1
    github.com/spf13/cobra v1.8.1
    go.etcd.io/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.1
)

require (
    github.com/AdaLogics/go-fuzz-headers v0.0.0-20230811130428-ced1acdcaa24 // indirect
    github.com/AdamKorcz/go-118-fuzz-build v0.0.0-20230306123547-8075edf89bb0 // indirect
    github.com/Microsoft/go-winio v0.6.1 // indirect
    github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim v0.11.4 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/cgroups v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/continuity v0.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/fifo v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/log v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/ttrpc v1.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/typeurl/v2 v2.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/coreos/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-events v0.0.0-20190806004212-e31b211e4f1c // indirect
    github.com/felixge/httpsnoop v1.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/logr v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/stdr v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.4 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/compress v1.16.0 // indirect
    github.com/moby/locker v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/mountinfo v0.6.2 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/sequential v0.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/signal v0.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/user v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/go-digest v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/image-spec v1.1.0-rc2.0.20221005185240-3a7f492d3f1b // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/selinux v1.11.0 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.9.3 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.24.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp v0.45.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel v1.19.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric v1.19.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace v1.19.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mod v0.11.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.17.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.3.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.13.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.13.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.10.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20230711160842-782d3b101e98 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc v0.0.0-20230731190214-cbb8c96f2d6d // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.58.3 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.33.0 // indirect
)

When I try to run my go program I get the following error:
panic: /debug/requests is already registered. You may have two independent copies of golang.org/x/net/trace in your binary, trying to maintain separate state. This may involve a vendored copy of golang.org/x/net/trace.

goroutine 1 [running]:
golang.org/x/net/trace.init.0()
        /home/jonatan5524/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/net@v0.17.0/trace/trace.go:123 +0xe8
exit status 2

It is caused by importing the module github.com/containerd/containerd v1.7.16 (when I removed it, the error was gone).
I have tried to use replace in the go.mod file but without success, and I have also tried different versions of the module, but they didn't help.
I will be glad some help with this issue! Thank you!
Update - able to reproduce the issue
I have created and new go program and started to import some of the modules, the combination of the etcd module and containerd module caused the issue:
main.go:
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/containerd/containerd"
    clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    fmt.Println(containerd.DefaultSnapshotter)
    fmt.Println(clientv3.ErrNoAvailableEndpoints.Error())
}

go.mod:
module github.com/jonatan5524/test-go

go 1.22.7

require (
    github.com/containerd/containerd v1.7.16
    go.etcd.io/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible
)

require (
    github.com/AdaLogics/go-fuzz-headers v0.0.0-20230811130428-ced1acdcaa24 // indirect
    github.com/AdamKorcz/go-118-fuzz-build v0.0.0-20230306123547-8075edf89bb0 // indirect
    github.com/Microsoft/go-winio v0.6.1 // indirect
    github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim v0.11.4 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/cgroups v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/continuity v0.4.2 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/fifo v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/log v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/ttrpc v1.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/containerd/typeurl/v2 v2.1.1 // indirect
    github.com/coreos/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-events v0.0.0-20190806004212-e31b211e4f1c // indirect
    github.com/felixge/httpsnoop v1.0.3 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/logr v1.2.4 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/stdr v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/golang/groupcache v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.4 // indirect
    github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/klauspost/compress v1.16.0 // indirect
    github.com/moby/locker v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/mountinfo v0.6.2 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/sequential v0.5.0 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/signal v0.7.0 // indirect
    github.com/moby/sys/user v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/go-digest v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/image-spec v1.1.0-rc2.0.20221005185240-3a7f492d3f1b // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/opencontainers/selinux v1.11.0 // indirect
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1 // indirect
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.9.3 // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.24.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp v0.45.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel v1.19.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric v1.19.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace v1.19.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mod v0.11.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.17.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.3.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.13.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.13.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.10.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20230711160842-782d3b101e98 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc v0.0.0-20230731190214-cbb8c96f2d6d // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.58.3 // indirect
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.33.0 // indirect
)

The error above reproduced

Importing github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.7.16 alone doesn't trigger the problem. It would help to create a [mre] which demonstrates the error.

@JimB thank you for the note, I reproduced the issue in a new clean program and updated my question.

You should import go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3, not go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3. You end up with go.etcd.io/etcd v2.3.8+incompatible in your go.mod, which is ancient and wrong. When you import it correctly, the line will read go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3 v3.5.16.

thank you! it solved my issue
